# Why am I getting a 'Unable to locate stream wrapper' message when using unlink() in php?

Tags: php, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file from the server using the `unlink(`) function with php.

Here is my code:

```
$photo_to_delete = 'http://www.example.com/images/uploads/properties/197/IMG_0002.jpg';
unlink($photo_to_delete);
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: Unable to locate stream wrapper
>   in
>   /nfs/c09/h01/mnt/137110/domains/www.example.com/html/listers/edit_photos.php
>   on line 43

Line 43 is where I have the unlink() function is.

Why am I getting a 'Unable to locate stream wrapper' message when using unlink() in php?

Comment: Thank god you didn't misspell that and accidentally did `unlink("http://www.google.com");`. You'd never hear the end of it!

Comment: @KerrekSB LOL I would be irate! :P

Comment: Is this URL supposed to be on your own/on the same server or on some other server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't delete a file remotely like that. Try using a relative path. Or even an absolute path (minus the `http://domain.com` part).

In other words:

```
unlink('/images/uploads/properties/197/IMG_0002.jpg'); // relative path
unlink('/var/www/html/images/uploads/properties/197/IMG_0002.jpg'); // absolute
```

Or better yet, if you're going to use an absolute path, try prefixing it with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/uploads/properties/197/IMG_0002.jpg');
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete something over the HTTP protocol, period.
See the table at http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php.

To clarify, the HTTP protocol only does *requests*. You may well send a request that basically contains "please delete file x", but there needs to be a server/program/script behind the target URL that actually fulfills this request. You cannot simply ask random URLs to delete themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) does in fact interface with PHPs stream wrapper API, but most wrappers don't implement the method.

There is a `DELETE` method for HTTP. But it's unlikely your server has that implemented. (Though a simple [`Script DELETE /delete.php`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#action) could be set up. Not very advisable sans authorization, obviously!)
And then you would need [`curl`](http://php.net/curl) or the [`http`](http://php.net/http) extension (or even `fsockopen`) to actually send a proper request for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete files on your server (the same where the php script runs) use relative or absolute path as [mmmshuddup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486233/mmmshuddup) said. If the file is located somewhere else you should use  some kind of network protocol for file management such as FTP... If this is your use case you can take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-delete.php